# Kafka redshift connector throwing NullPointerException

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect Redshift to Kafka cluster, with Redshift Sink Connector. I'm currently testing out with standalone mode.

However, I keep getting the error below. I believe the configuration files are correct because JdbcDbWriter was connected successfully. I also checked the message from Kafka wasn't Null. Do I have more to check ? Thank you very much in advance.

```
[2020-05-18 08:08:30,915] INFO Attempting to open connection #1 to Redshift (io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:87)
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,301] INFO JdbcDbWriter Connected (io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter:49)
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,458] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=redshift-source-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:566)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:174)
        at io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:72)
        at io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:326)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,467] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=redshift-source-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:186)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:568)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:326)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:228)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:174)
        at io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:72)
        at io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:546)
        ... 10 more
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,469] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=redshift-source-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:187)
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,469] INFO Stopping task (io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:105)
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,469] INFO Closing connection #1 to Redshift (io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:113)
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,470] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-redshift-source-0, groupId=connect-redshift-source] Revoke previously assigned partitions TopicTest-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:292)
[2020-05-18 08:08:31,471] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-redshift-source-0, groupId=connect-redshift-source] Member connector-consumer-redshift-source-0-c72b053d-8ce9-4337-9757-04e438dd6d0f sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator b-3.inside-dev-messag.ktn4r3.c3.kafka.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:979)
```

I gave 2 property files, and they are also listed below.

```
name=redshift-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.aws.redshift.RedshiftSinkConnector
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers=<Bootstrap Servers>
confluent.topic.replication.factor=2
tasks.max=1

topics=TopicTest

aws.redshift.domain=<Domain>
aws.redshift.port=5439
aws.redshift.database=testdb
aws.redshift.user=<User>
aws.redshift.password=<Pwd>
auto.create=false

type=sink
```

and

```
bootstrap.servers=<Bootstrap Servers>

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
plugin.path=share/java,share/confluent-hub-components
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the root cause in my case was that schemas were not enabled. Try changing the following config values to true after ensuring that the messages do have schemas on the records.

```
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

To see if the messages have schema enabled check the json message in Kafka and you should see a "schema" part and the "payload" part. That will tell you that schemas are part of the data in the messages.

If you dont see the schema in the json, make sure, that schemas are enabled on the source connector too.

I was helped by the answer I got on github that you can see [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/860#issuecomment-631084969).

Another related issue is [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/789).

Comment: Hi! The problem was key being null, and the problem EXACTLY was nullpointexception. I didn't know that the kafka message from topic had a default key of null.

Comment: @PiljaeChae, so how did you resolve the issue? I'm facing the same as yours